# Call to strcpy() raises signal SIGABRT

Tags: c, sigabrt, strcpy

I know it's a common question but I didn't find a suitable explanation yet! My project compiles but I keep getting the ***Thread: signal SIGABRT!*** - the **strcpy** function; nothing's written in the debugger window and when I debug step by step the test works perfectly fine and I get success, but when I try to run it again I get that error!
How can I fix it?

here's my code :

```
static char* copyMember(const char* str){
    if(str==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    char* newStr=malloc((strlen(str)+1)*sizeof(char));
    if(newStr==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    return strcpy(newStr, str);
}
```

Comment: It should be input parameter `str` related, the logic is no problem in your code

Comment: I thought about that but in the debugger window I can see that:
str = (const char*) "moshe"
*str=m

newStr=(char*) "moshe"
*newStr=m

Comment: I tried running this code, and it works. Perhaps you aren't importing or linking the proper libraries when you build. What are your `#include`s? Do you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: No compiler warnings!

Comment: @RawanKhazen The memory related problem like overflow will probably trigger  Thread: signal SIGABRT!  even when you can run it under debug mode. The `str` argument or your code exec context could result in it. So, paste the code context would help.

Comment: On which OS, with which compiler, compilation command, standard C library, ...? `SIGABRT` is generally related to `abort()`  being called (perhaps by a failing `assert`). Very probably the issue is elsewhere. Try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if possible.

Comment: BTW, many implementations have a [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) doing exactly what your `copyMember`  (not a very nice name, BTW) does.

Comment: Is it multi-threaded - in which case is another thread doing something with `str`

Comment: @EricTsui you were right, I finally figured out where the problem was and could fix it!
Thanks guys :))

Comment: @RawanKhazen Glad you resolved it. And you can also update/edit again to share your fix with others if you'd like.

Comment: Does the code provide the prototype to `strcpy()` (typically by `#include`ing `<string.h>` and is compiled on 64bits?